# Android BluetoothLeAdvertiser not working when used by Nativescript

Tags: java, android, typescript, bluetooth-lowenergy, nativescript

I am trying to create a Nativescript application that will allow me to send Bluetooth low energy advertisements. As there are no Nativescript plugins that enable this, I have gone ahead and created a java library (will add swift library later, but that's beside the point) that should enable advertising.

After creating the plugin and integrating the java library with Typescript, I could see that, although the startAdvertising() method was being called, the advertisements were not being sent (They weren't showing up on my BLE Sniffer.)

Because the advertising happens in the java code, I can't find a way to debug it (For instance, I can't get a success/fail message from the callback, since I can't Toast outside of an activity, or I can't print a message to the console).

I am wondering if anyone could provide insight into why the advertisements are not sending, or a method of debugging the java code to allow me to debug it.

**Ble Advertiser Library**

```
//imports...

class Advertiser {

    public String startAdvertising(int manufacturerId, byte[] payload, int duration){
        //Acquire instance of the BluetoothLeAdvertiser
        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothLeAdvertiser leAdvertiser = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();

        AdvertiseSettings settings =
                new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
                        .setTimeout(duration)
                        .setConnectable(false)
                        .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                        .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH)
                        .build();

        AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .setIncludeDeviceName(false)
                .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)
                .addManufacturerData(manufacturerId, payload)
                .build();

        AdvertiseCallback callback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
                super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
                super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
            }
        };

        leAdvertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, callback);

        return "Method finished.";
    }
}
```

**jsIntegrator.js**

```
module.exports = {
startAdvertising: function(manufacturerId, payload, timeout=5000) {
        var advertiser = new com.nslibs.moble.Advertiser();
        console.log("Result of startAdvertising: " + advertiser.startAdvertising(
            manufacturerId, payload, timeout));
        //Prints Result of startAdvertising: MethodFinished
    }
}
```

**tsIntegrator.ts**

```
export function startAdvertising(
    manufacturerId: number, toSend: number[], timeout?: number);
```

**mainClass.ts**

```
import * as Ble from "my-ble-plugin";    
export class Main{
    foo(){
        Ble.startAdvertising(2, [4,6,8]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do the last `leAdvertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, callback);` part in JavaScript, implementing the interface in Javascript, again using the `new` syntax like so: `new full.package.name.AdvertiseCallback({ onStartSuccess: (settingsInEffect) => { ... }, onStartFailure: (code) => { ... })`. This way you can console log all you want in the callbacks, or even debug them with VSCode/Chrome DevTools.

Comment: @pkanev I wasn't even aware that was an option, pretty silly of me :P I will be doing that for sure. Many thanks!

Comment: Let me drop that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider making the last `leAdvertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, callback);` call in JavaScript, implementing the interface in Javascript like so:

```js
new full.package.name.AdvertiseCallback({ 
  onStartSuccess: (settingsInEffect) => { ... }, 
  onStartFailure: (code) => { ... }
)
```

Doing that gives you control over the code you implement, e.g. you can console log all you want in the callbacks, or even debug them with VSCode/Chrome DevTools.